# How to remove specific engine page and engine menu item from refinerycms menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I've created an engine in refinerycms where i'm pulling the data onto the homepage. Refinerycms automatically creates a page and a menu item for this engine.

How can i delete the engine page as well as remove it from my menu bar?

menu.html.erb

```
<%
  # Collect the root items.
  # ::Refinery::Menu is smart enough to remember all of the items in the original collection.
  if (roots = local_assigns[:roots] || (collection ||= refinery_menu_pages).roots).present?
    dom_id ||= 'menu'
    css = [(css || 'menu clearfix')].flatten.join(' ')
    hide_children = Refinery::Core.menu_hide_children if hide_children.nil?
-%>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <%= render :partial => '/refinery/menu_branch', :collection => roots,
               :locals => {
                 :hide_children => hide_children,
                 :sibling_count => (roots.length - 1),
                 :menu_levels => local_assigns[:menu_levels],
                 :apply_css => true #if you don't care about class='first' class='last' or class='selected' set apply_css to false for speed.
               } -%>
  </ul>
</div>

<% end -%>
```

menu_branch.html.erb

```
<%
  if !!local_assigns[:apply_css] and (classes = menu_branch_css(local_assigns)).any?
    css = "class='#{classes.join(' ')}'".html_safe
  end
-%>
<li<%= ['', css].compact.join(' ').gsub(/\ *$/, '').html_safe %>>
<%= link_to(menu_branch.title, refinery.url_for(menu_branch.url)) -%>
  <% if ( (children = menu_branch.children unless hide_children).present? &&
          (!local_assigns[:menu_levels] || menu_branch.ancestors.length < local_assigns[:menu_levels]) ) -%>
    <ul class='clearfix'>
      <%= render :partial => '/refinery/menu_branch', :collection => children,
                 :locals => {
                   :apply_css => local_assigns[:apply_css],
                   :hide_children => !!hide_children,
                   :menu_levels => local_assigns[:menu_levels]
                 } -%>
    </ul>
  <% end -%>
</li>
```

The menu item in particular that i want removed from the menu bar is "new programs"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found that when editing a page in Refinerycms if you click advanced options, there is a checkbox on whether to include the page in the public menu or not.

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for. Just needed to make the "blog" the default page and hide the "home" option.

Comment: This will stop it appearing on the menu, but it won't help you delete the page -- e.g. if you've somehow accidentally 'seeded' the database twice and now have "Blog" pages duplicated!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way do to this is to remove the page from the console :

- Enter in the rails console : `bundle exec rails c`
- Find the page you want to delete : `page = Refinery::Page.find("your-page-id")`
- Destroy it : `page.destroy!`

Notice that "your-page-id" should be replace by the id of your page ;), you can see it in the URL when you access this page in the frontend or backend.

Also we use the `destroy!` method because, by default, this page is set to undeletable.

Finally, you can prevent the creation of this page by editing the seeds file of your engine.

Comment: Now i still want the engine to come up in the admin menu so that a user can add/remove new programs, but i just don't want it to show up under the "pages" link in the admin, or the main navigation of the site. Will your changes do this or will they remove it from everything?

Comment: Yes my changes will do this. It will remove the page object created, to remove the engine tab from the admin, it's another story.

Answer (score 3):

You could also add the skip-frontend option when generating the engine:

```
rails generate refinery:engine NAME [field:type field:type] --skip-frontend
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does in more detail?

Comment: there will be no front-end pages and menu entries, just the back-end part so you won't need to exclude the engine from the menu.

Comment: This has proved to me useful more times than I can count.